# Checking if dataframe groups contain substring from provided list (case insensitive)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, substring, pandas-groupby

How do I print/return the value based on values from another column?

```
df = my_df[['Index', 'FRUITS']]
print(df)

 Index            FRUITS
     7       Green Apple
     7             Mango
     7            Orange
     7        Strawberry
     9         Pineapple
     9            Banana
     9            Grapes
    10   Orange (Unripe)
    10              Plum

L = ['apple', 'orange']
```

Here, I want to **check** if the string **Apple** ***or*** **Orange** are **present** in the **substring** for ***every Index*** irrespective of case, *return those serial numbers where **either** one of these 2 fruits **aren't found!***

I tried using approaches from different answers and tried groupby and iterating over fruits:

```
out = df.groupby('Index')['FRUITS'].apply(lambda x: L in x)

TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not list
```

So, the **expected output** is:

```
[9, 10]
```

Comment: I understand why 10 is ther in expected output because it has Orange. But why 9?

Comment: I guess you got it in opposite way. 10 is there because it doesn't have apple and 9 because it doesn't have both orange and apple. I want Index when even 1 of the value is missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using `str.findall`

```
result = df.groupby('Index')['FRUITS'].apply(' '.join).str.lower().str.findall('\\bapple\\b|\\borange\\b').str.len() < 2

list(result[result].index)
```

---

```
[9, 10]
```

Comment: I have a huge data of around 3000 records, now when I search apple the result is count = 2791, when I search orange the result is count = 800. But when I search for both values it gives 1895 as result. But if apple is missing in 2791 records, shouldn't the answer be 2791 instead of 1895.

Comment: does apple and orange present in a single string..? also your numbers dont make sense, if 3000 are total and you want those strings where both fruits aren't present so the result should be 2108 (1895 are where both are present).. .

Comment: also how are you searching..normal search for apple will consider string with "pineapple" in it as legit

Comment: I want data where either one isn't present so if apple isn't present in 2791 records, even if orange has an 800 number, the total records with missing value should be 2791 or greater (considering oranges were not found in different records and not the same as apples.)

Comment: One more thing, if you test only orange in the mentioned example, the expected output is [9] as only 9 doesn't have any substring orange but the result from above code is [7,8,9]

Comment: Oh! I see the number at the end in your code plays a vital role. More values equal is the number. Thanks.